# How can I specify REG_EXPAND_SZ entries in a .REG file?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

I'm trying to use a batch script and a `.reg` file to set up some custom services.  Most of the keys are being set up properly, but I need to set the `DependOnService` key for some of the services, which is normally a multi-string.  Is it possible to set this key from a `.reg` file, or will manual entry be required?

Comment: good question. it's a shame that after 9 years there is no fully correct answer yet.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn The accepted answer was close enough that just a little more research led me to a full solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`REG_MULTI_SZ` data in `.reg` files must be encoded in hexadecimal.  If the content never changes, you can create a dummy item in your registry with the data, export it, and adjust that to your needs.

If it does change, it will probably be far easier to use the `reg` program included with Windows to add it.  To do so, call `reg` in this format:

```bat
Reg Add <KEY> /v <NAME> /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d <DATA> /s <SEPERATOR>
```

The seperator switch is optional.  If not used, the strings to be written should be seperated by the escape sequence for the null character (`\0`).  For instance, to add a item named `Flair` to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WhizBang\Excite-O-Rama` with the strings `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` you would run:

```bat
Reg Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\WhizBang\Excite-O-Rama /v Flair /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d foo\0bar\0baz
```

To separate the data with commas instead, you would run:

```bat
Reg Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\WhizBang\Excite-O-Rama /v Flair /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d foo,bar,baz /s ,
```

For more information, consult Microsoft Docs for the [`Reg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) command.

Comment: Great answer (using a `.bat` file with `reg` command instead of a `.reg` file), but why does it speak about REG_MULTI_SZ when the question is about REG_EXPAND_SZ?

Answer (score 5):

- `dword:` = `DWORD`
- `hex(2):` = Expandable-String
- `hex(7):` = Multi-String

A `DWORD` is a 32-bit unsigned integer (decimal range: `0` - `4294967295`), and, in the registry, a `DWORD` always begins with `0x` and has 8 digits that follow `0x`.  This can be in decimal or hexadecimal format; for example, `1000` can be written as `0x00001000` or `0x000003e8`.

`DWORDS` can only make use of the digits `0` - `9`.  Strings, of any kind, always use ASCII, and in ACSII, `1000` can only be written as `31,30,30,30`.  For the String data type, ASCII works in the background without you even knowing because the computer only understands 1s and 0s.

For Expandable-String and Multi-String data types, these save your entries as a series of ASCII codes in a hexadecimal format, separated by commas and hex zeroes; so an Expandable-String of `1000` would be `hex(2):31,00,30,00,30,00,30,00`

Let's convert `%PROGRAMFILES%` into an Expandable-String:

1. Use an [ASCII to Hex Conversion Tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html), input `%PROGRAMFILES%` into the text box, User defined Output delimiter: `%`, select Convert, and it will give you:

   ```powershell
   %25%50%52%4F%47%52%41%4D%46%49%4C%45%53%25
   ```
2. Copy/paste that result into a text editor: Move the first `%` to the end, Find/Replace all `%` with `,00,` and remove the comma at the very end of the string.  You should get:

   ```powershell
   25,00,50,00,52,00,4F,00,47,00,52,00,41,00,4D,00,46,00,49,00,4C,00,45,00,53,00,25,00
   ```
3. Finally:

   ```powershell
   hex(2):25,00,50,00,52,00,4F,00,47,00,52,00,41,00,4D,00,46,00,49,00,4C,00,45,00,53,00,25,00
   ```

This lesson contains all the knowledge required to reverse engineer any hex-coded registry entry that is not encrypted.

Comment: The hotfile link is just a 7z archive with a html page (that contains the converter) stored inside. Why not just link to the web page itself?

Comment: To avoid link rot please post all relevant information in your answer. for more information on how to answer questions please see [answer]

Comment: 0x00001000 without 0x, right?