# Adding %USERPROFILE% to a command in the Windows registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm trying to write a registry hack that will streamline some of my setup tasks when I create a new VM or repave my laptop. One thing I'm doing is switching to portable versions (synced in Dropbox) of a bunch of my favorite apps, including Notepad++.

I want to create a registry entry to allow me to have the Open with Notepad++ option in my right click menu, which is the only thing I'm missing with the portable version. I'm getting an error, though:

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the 
appropriate permissions to access the item.
```

Here's my `.reg` file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Notepad++]
"Icon"="%USERPROFILE%\\Dropbox\\Programs\\Setup\\Icons\\Notepad++.ico"
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Notepad++\command]
@="%USERPROFILE%\\Dropbox\\Programs\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe %1"
```

The icon works perfectly. I can get the entry above to work fine if I hardcode `C:\Users\myusername`, but I'm going for portability here.

I'm pretty sure the issue is just finding the right escape sequence for the `%` symbols, but it's hard to say.

Suggestions?

EDIT: I went with the `add reg` command option, and after a bit of trial and error, here's the command that worked:

```
reg add HKCR\*\shell\OpenWithNotepad++\command /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /ve /d ^%USERPROFILE^%"\Dropbox\Programs\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1"
```

After running the command, I exported the results as a `.reg` file as well. Wins all around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use (expand) environment variables in the registry, the value must be of the type [`REG_EXPAND_SZ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/251794/how-can-i-specify-reg-expand-sz-entries-in-a-reg-file), it would be easiest to add that kind of value with the `reg` command rather than a [`.reg` file.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516).

```
reg add <KEY> /v <NAME> /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d <DATA>
```

See `reg add /?` for more information on this syntax.

You could also encode the data as hex. There's some examples of that [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=270750):

> `REG_EXPAND_SZ` data must be presented as what MS calls a *binary* data
>   type (subtype "2"), so the value must be formatted in a kind of
>   hexidecimal format, comma-delimited, two tokens per byte (padded with
>   zeros), with a terminating null byte of course (and further
>   explanation is obviously far beyond the scope of this article, and the
>   author won't be held responsible for anyone's misuse of the incomplete
>   information given thus far). So the line above will not work but
>   indicates the end result I wanted to achieve. As a real working .REG
>   -file entry the example above must be rendered as:

```
"SoMeThIng"="%WINDIR%\\system32"
```

becomes

```
"SoMeThIng"=hex(2):22,25,57,49,4e,44,49,52,25,5c,5c,73,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,22,00
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Stuck on the syntax of the command, though: `reg add HKCR\*\shell\Open with Notepad++\command /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /ve /d ^%USERPROFILE^%\Dropbox\Programs\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1` is generating a syntax error. Not really sure how to handle the space before the `%1`, either...

Comment: Put quotes around the strings... spaces get split into separate arguments, which becomes invalid syntax (more arguments than expected).

Comment: As crazy as it sounds, you can just put quotes around the spaces within the string.  `reg add HKCR\*\shell\OpenWithNotepad++\command /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /ve /d ^%USERPROFILE^%\Dropbox\Programs\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1`

Answer (score 0):

12 years later, on Windows 11, we still need hex strings for REG_EXPAND_SZ in .reg files. 
Writing reg.exe commands in a CMD file is still easier for this.

We can also do the following, when using reg.exe via CMD: 
let the env-vars **expand in CMD**, so they **enter the registry as plain strings**. 
The syntax is a bit simpler, as you leave out ^ before %, 
and quote the whole string. Remember to set the type as REG_SZ.

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\OpenWithNPP\command /t REG_SZ /ve /d "%AllUsersProfile%\apps\npp\notepad++.exe %1"

REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\OpenWithNPP\command /s
```

Result:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\OpenWithNPP\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\ProgramData\apps\npp\notepad++.exe %1
```

As long as you don't later move the "known folder" to some other place, 
the hard-coded path will keep on working.

%AllUsersProfile% is ancient, compatible with XP. 
%ProgramData% is the equivalent to use these days. 
But I do this for Mac users who have XP in a VM to run an old app. ;)

The actual path is different in XP, but using this method in a cmd script 
inserts the right path for the machine it runs on.